# Script tag not working in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have seen some post related to this, but could not get much help there.

I'm trying to pass an array from php file to a js file
here is the code in php file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head> ------ </head>

<body onload="gotofunction()">

<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['street']= $this->street;
  $_SESSION['city']= $this->city;
  $_SESSION['state']= $this->state;
  $_SESSION['zip']= $this->zip;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function voodoo(){
   alert('alert in voodoo');  // 1st alert
   document.contents.submit();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php echo "php text";   //1st echo
  $var= json_encode($this->variable);
  ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
 var1:'<?php echo $this->variable;?>',
 path:'<?php echo $this->path;?>'
 }

</script>
```

and the js file

```js
function gotofunction(){

    alert('alert number1');   //1st alert
    alert(' data '+data.var1 ); //2nd alert
    $.post(data.path+'res/data_controller/tablog1', {'var':data.var1},function(data){
     $('#pos1').html(data);
    });
 }
```

the problem I'm facing is that in the js file, the error comes as "data is not declared" and also the 2nd alert in js file doesn't work. In the php file php echos can be seen but not the alerts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: put your scripts before </body> tag

Comment: As the error suggests, 'data' is not declared in your function. You call gotofunction() before the data var has been declared in your doc and you don't pass the var to it. You could move the gotofunction() call inside the same script tag after you set data, then either call data as a var of window (window.data) or pass it directly to the function gotofunction(data);

Comment: you're also outputting before header. The session must be started before any output.

Answer (score 0):

Add JS before the body like this.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['street']= $this->street;
  $_SESSION['city']= $this->city;
  $_SESSION['state']= $this->state;
  $_SESSION['zip']= $this->zip;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head> ------ </head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
    var1:'<?php echo $this->variable;?>',
    path:'<?php echo $this->path;?>'
    }
function gotofunction(){

    alert('alert number1');     //1st alert
    alert(' data '+data.var1 ); //2nd alert
    $.post(data.path+'res/data_controller/tablog1', {'var':data.var1},function(data){
     $('#pos1').html(data);
    });
    }

</script>

<body onload="gotofunction()">



<script type="text/javascript">
  function voodoo(){
    alert('alert in voodoo');  // 1st alert
   document.contents.submit();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php echo "php text";   //1st echo
  $var= json_encode($this->variable);
  ?>
```